# How do I resolve the following error while opening a ".rattle" file? "Error in .RGtkCall("S_gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new_with_backend

Tags: r, windows-10, rstudio, rattle, rgtk2

I have R Version 3.5.2, RStudio Version 1.1.463, and Rattle Version 5.2.5. on 2 Windows 10 machines.

After launching Rattle successfully I click on the "Open" button to attempt to open a .rattle file.  After clicking the open button I get the following message in the RStudio Console 
"Error in .RGtkCall("S_gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new_with_backend", title,  : 
  Could not parse enum value load"
I have re-installed  R, R Studio, RGtk2, GTK+ on both machines and get the same error on both machines.

Answer (score 1):

Check which version of RGtk2 is loaded in R if its version 2.20.36 try reverting back to version 2.20.35 that solved my issue.

Comment: To confirm that there was a change to 2.20.36 that has broken rattle. Currently working on it but a workaround for now is to install 2.20.35.

Comment: How?  Error:  cannot open URL 'https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/RGtk2_2.20.35.zip': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'

Answer (score 1):

A change to the RGtk2 package from 2.20.35 to 2.20.36 has resulted in a latent rattle bug being found. For now revert to the previous version of RGtk2.

For Linux:

```
> install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RGtk2/RGtk2_2.20.35.tar.gz", repos=NULL)
```

For Windows

```
> install.packages("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2019-02-01/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/RGtk2_2.20.35.zip", repos=NULL)
```

I hope to have a fix for rattle soon.

Comment: I can't find RGtk2_2.20.35.zip anywhere.  ..contrib/3.3-3.6 have been replaced with ...36.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I've updated the link to point to RGtk2_2.20.35.zip on MRAN.